# Fast way to compute average for neural network weights

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras

### Issue

I am trying to calculate the average of `n` neural network weights (keras\tensorflow). I want to optimize the computation as much as possible.

### My solution

```
def get_avg_weights(array_weights):
    new_weights = list()
    for weights_list_tuple in zip(*array_weights):
        new_weights.append(
            [sum(weights_) / len(weights_) \
             for weights_ in zip(*weights_list_tuple)])
    return new_weights

if __name__ == 'main':
    array_weights = deque([], maxlen = 5)   # collection of different NN weights
    array_weights.append(weights1)
    array_weights.append(weights2)
    array_weights.append(weights3)

    avg = get_avg_weights(array_weights)
```

The result is correct, but it is relatively slow. 
For 5 sets of weights, and a NN of 4 layers and 1000 hidden neurons per layer, it takes `34ms` to compute the average. Since I need to do this about 600K times with different set of weights, I want to optimize the computation as much as possible. Does anybody know a way to speed up the code?

Comment: What is the type of array_weights?

Comment: the type is a `collection.deque` of 5 lists, and each list is a np.ndarray obtained with `model.get_weights()`

Comment: Have you tried using `np.ndarray.sum` as opposed to `sum(sp.ndarray)`?

Comment: `weights_` is a `tuple`, so `np.ndarray.sum()` is not possible